# Dynamic landing page in Alfresco Share

Tags: authentication, customization, alfresco-share

I'm trying to figure out how to implement a mechanism that decides dynamically what's the landing page for a user.

I know that the default landing page is relatively easy to customize, as you can see in the following link:

http://blogs.alfresco.com/wp/ddraper/2011/11/01/advanced-share-customization-part-1/

http://zscribble.wordpress.com/2012/02/13/how-to-change-user-landing-page-in-alfresco-share/

But it is not enough because I need go a little further; after the successful authentication of any user, I need to retrieve the site/s that a user belongs to and then redirect to the dashboard of any of the sites.

I guess there is any authentication service that redirects to `TOMCAT/webapps/share/site-index.jsp`, and from here to either the user dashboard or a site dashboard, depending on the parameters received. If I'm right with my assumption, I understand I just should customize such supposed authentication service in order to get the user's sites and then redirect to the appropriate site dashboard's URL.

Am I in the right way? If not, any idea on how to proceed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible approach in order to implement a mechanism which dynamically redirects to a page after a successful authentication in Alfresco Share.

The easiest way consists in the next steps:

1. Change the default landing page by updating the value of the tag `<root-page>` in the file `alfresco\site-data\configurations\slingshot.site.configuration.xml` (the default value is `site-index`).
2. Create a custom Surf page according to the value defined before.
3. Create a custom template-instance
4. Create a custom FreeMarker template, exclusively containing a region that loads a webscript (will be created in the next step).
5. Implement a webscript that decides whatever a URL to redirect to (in my case I have to retrieve the user's sites via RESTful API and then redirect to a site's dashboard)
6. Perform the redirection similarly to the `accept-invite component` is doing

The other possible way is to override the classes `PageView` and `PageViewResolver`, this way you can perform the redirection to the landing page in a single step rather than two steps, what is more efficient as a consequence. I didn't developed this solution so I cannot give more details but according to what an Alfresco Engineer says, it is viable to achieve.

If you want to know more about this, read [this thread](https://forums.alfresco.com/en/viewtopic.php?f=48&t=47154).